# Jenkins pipeline: kubectl: not found

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubectl

I have the following Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
  stage('Apply Kubernetes files') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'jenkins-deployer', serverUrl: 'https://192.168.64.2:8443']) {
      sh 'kubectl apply -f '
    }
  }
}
```

While running it, I got "kubectl: not found". I installed Kubernetes-cli plugin to Jenkins, generated secret key via `kubectl create sa jenkins-deployer`. What's wrong here?

Comment: Also, I installed Kubectl (/usr/local/bin), but still it's not found

Comment: Did you try to use the complete path of the command? You can try something like this: `/usr/local/bin/kubectl apply -f` or `$(which kubectl) apply -f`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a fairly old question, but I decided to describe an easy workaround that might be helpful.
To use the [Kubernetes CLI](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/) plugin we need to have an executor with `kubectl` installed.

One possible way to get `kubectl` is to install it in the Jenkins pipeline like in the snipped below:
**NOTE:** I'm using `./kubectl get pods` to list all Pods in the default Namespace. Additionally, you may need to change `kubectl` version (`v1.20.5`).

```
node {
  stage('List pods') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kubernetes-config']) {
        sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'  
        sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'  
        sh './kubectl get pods'
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, in the Console Output, we can see that it works as expected:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
  ...
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod u+x ./kubectl
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./kubectl get pods
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-zhxwb   1/1     Running   0          34s
my-jenkins-0    2/2     Running   0          134m
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. The only thing I'd add - the credentials have to be x509 and in my case (minikube), I had to provide a url to the 'withKubeConfig' as well.

Comment: How can we do the same thing in Windows?

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation and the code !

Comment: should be marked as the answer...

@matt_j thank you for taking the time to post this.

Answer (score 0):

You call `kubectl` from the shellscript step. To be able to do that the agent (node) executing the build needs to have kubectl available as executable.

Comment: I did chmod +x kubectl, but still kubectl is not found =(

Comment: I assume that /usr/local/bin/kubectl is not in the path, could you try running it with `sh '/usr/local/bin/kubectl apply -f '` Make sure the kubectl is really on the actual agent node installed.